# Flask container can't access localhost:8080, but can access localhost:7474

Tags: python, docker, neo4j

I am following this tutorial right here:https://github.com/elementsinteractive/flask-graphql-neo4j

When I spin up the container everything seems to work fine and I am able to access localhost:7474, but I am not able to access localhost:8080. Also when I look at my docker container says this:

```
2023-10-20 14:49:04 /bin/sh: /app/wait-for.sh: not found
2023-10-20 14:49:04 Waiting for :...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021851/docker-compose-error-wait-for-it-sh-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: How do you try to access port 8080 and what error(s) do you get?

Comment: i just open google and type in localhost:8080. it just says cant connect . Im pretty new to data engineering so not sure what else im missing.