# Docker - Restart specific container if another restarts

Tags: docker, containers, restart

Is it possible to restart a container if another container fails and restarts?

I have a server container and multiple client containers, I want to have it that if the server container fails and restarts, that one of the client containers restarts as well.

I've already used the restart policies (always, on-failure etc.) but this would be linking two containers and triggering the restart of container A if container B restarts.

Comment: I don't think Compose can do this, but it also seems like a little bit of an odd requirement.  How would you do it without Compose?  How would you do it if the servers and clients were on different hosts?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be quite similar, if not duplicate, of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710767/what-is-the-alternative-to-condition-form-of-depends-on-in-docker-compose-versio).

TL;DR: There has been a shift from defining complex restart policies in docker/docker-compose superseded by explicitly checking for dependencies from *within* your service so it is deployment agnostic. Therefore, the recommendation is to create specific checks *within* the container that 'depends' on other services and crash properly when they are not met so that a simple `restart: always` policy is all that is needed.