# Don't spin up dependent containers if dependency container healthcheck results in unhealthy

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 3 services defined in docker-compose `A`, `B` and `C`. `B` and `C`  `depends_on` `A`. If `A`'s `healthcheck` results in `unhealthy`, I want other 2 containers not be spinned up. Currently, containers `B` and `C` are started only when container `A` is started with `healthy` status, and this is my expected behaviour. However, if container `A` becomes `unhealthy` after it gets created, I don't want dependent containers to be started, currently when `A` is created and becomes `unhealthy` only one of the other 2 container exits (sometimes `A` exits and other times `B` but not both). Here's the output when `A` is unhealthy.

```
Creating A ... done 
Creating C ... done  
ERROR: for B  Container "1339a6d12091" is unhealthy. ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

As we can see here in the ERROR message, only for `B` it shows `1339a6d12091`(container `A`) is unhealthy. Whereas it should have reported this error for both `B` and `C` containers.

docker-compose

```
version: '2.3'
    
    services:
      B:
        image: base_image
        depends_on:
           A:
             condition: service_healthy
        entrypoint:  bash -c "/app/entrypoint_scripts/execute_B.sh"
      C:
        image: base_image
        depends_on:
          A:
            condition: service_healthy
        entrypoint: bash -c "/app/entrypoint_scripts/execute_C.sh"
      A:
        image: base_image
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD-SHELL", "test -f /tmp/compliance/executedfetcher"]
          interval: 30s
          timeout: 3600s
          retries: 1
        entrypoint: bash -c "/app/entrypoint_scripts/execute_A.sh"
```

**My Expectation:** `B` and `C` should wait for `A` to become `healthy` before starting (which is working fine for me). If `A` starts and become `unhealthy` without becoming `healthy` even for once `B` and `C` should not start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the alternative to condition form of depends\_on in docker-compose Version 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710767/what-is-the-alternative-to-condition-form-of-depends-on-in-docker-compose-versio)

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: @crizzis Nope, that doesn't seems to be helpful.

Comment: The answer tells you that `condition` is no longer supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container `A` was exiting immediately after becoming unhealthy, as a result, the `status: unhealthy` was not available for long enough for other containers to read its value. The `status: unhealthy` was visible only for a fraction of a second and in that fraction of a second only one of the container (either `A` or `B`) was able to read it.

I added a `sleep 100` statement in the `execute_A.sh` entrypoint script after the container was becoming `unhealthy` so that both `B` and `C` can easily read `A`'s `status`, and that fixed the issue.