# Docker Compose: depends_on with condition -> invalid type, should be an array

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have the following compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: docker-dev.art.intern/wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: docker-dev.art.intern/wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:4020/actuator/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper

  app-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: test/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      app:
        condition: service_healthy
```

As you can see im implementing a healthcheck for the app and I use `service_healthy` condition.
But that leads to the error:

```
The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app-test.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

Is there a way to fix that issue?

If I change to array sanytax:

```yaml
...

  app-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: test/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app:
          condition: service_healthy
```

The error changes to:

```
The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app-test.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Comment: Try running the compose file with `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`

Comment: Thank's Dillon (docker compose) this work for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This appears to have been removed in version 3 of the docker compose specification, but then re-introduced in version 3.9.

See https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#long-syntax-1

Note that this seems to require Compose V2, which is executed as `docker compose` on the latest docker binary.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command

Answer (score 8):

you can do that with a compose file [version 2.1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on), but it was removed in compose file [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on).

> There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:
>
> - depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

yet, will advise you not to downgrade your compose file. but rather handle it appropriately with a wrapper script.

you might find [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), [dockerize](https://github.com/powerman/dockerize), and/or [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for) handy.

in compose version 3 you can use [depends long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1) to specify a condition

> `condition`: condition under which dependency is considered satisfied
>
> - `service_started`: is an equivalent of the short syntax described above
> - `service_healthy`: specifies that a dependency is expected to be “healthy” (as indicated by healthcheck) before starting a dependent service.
> - `service_completed_successfully`: specifies that a dependency is expected to run to successful completion before starting a dependent service.

e.g.

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Comment: With compose 3.4 you get healthchecks, apparently with which you can add custom code for checks. I am not sure these wait scripts are useful anymore.

Answer (score -3):

**Edit**: this only solves the YAML error, and still doesn't produce a working docker-compose since depends_on is not valid in [Compose version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/). You need either [Compose version 2.1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-21) or the [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

---

You're missing a `-` to make `depends_on` an array:

```
  app-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: test/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app:
          condition: service_healthy
```

Notice the `-` before `app`. Without it, `services.app-test.depends_on` will be an object, not an array. Also pay attention to the amount of spaces: if `condition` is in the same column as `app`, you will also get an undesired result.

When decoding your YAML, this is what you get (in JSON):

```json
{
  "app-test": {
    "build": {
      "context": "./",
      "dockerfile": "test/Dockerfile"
    },
    "depends_on": {
      "app": {
        "condition": "service_healthy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the added `-`:

```json
{
  "app-test": {
    "build": {
      "context": "./",
      "dockerfile": "test/Dockerfile"
    },
    "depends_on": [
      {
        "app": {
          "condition": "service_healthy"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do like you say the error changes to:

`The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app-test.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be a string`

Comment: Seems like doing `- app:` is not allowed. With array notation it must be `- app` without ":". And with that you cant provide the condition.

Comment: From a quick look at the [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on), it seems `condition:` inside `depends_on:` is not supported anymore - it was only in [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on).

Comment: Also, compose v2 doesn't need the `-`, since `depends_on` is not an array in v2

Comment: With version 2 I get the exact same error. And if v3 does not support it anymore, how are we supposed to handle this now, if one service depends on the startup of another service.

Comment: I don't think it's the exact same error, it's probably a bit different. More specifically, you need the 2.1 version, as described in the documentation. I'm not very up to date with `docker compose`, but it seems now there is also an unified [compose specification](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md) which supports `condition` again. You might also want to use a wrapper script to wait for other services to be up.

Comment: For more details, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710767/what-is-the-alternative-to-condition-form-of-depends-on-in-docker-compose-versio), which talks both about alternatives and about the unified compose spec.