# The Compose file './docker-compose-deploy.yml' is invalid on Linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, bash, docker-compose

I'm incredibly new to Linux, and have been trying to configure Nginx and Let's Encrypt on my virtual machine using a `cli.sh` file.

After running the script, I run into the following error:

```
WARNING: The CURRENT_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DOCKER_GROUP variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose-deploy.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.cli: 'profiles'
services.certbot.healthcheck value Additional properties are not allowed ('start                                                                             _period' was unexpected)
services.nginx.healthcheck value Additional properties are not allowed ('start_p                                                                             eriod' was unexpected)
services.cron.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.certbot.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.nginx.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

My `cli.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
      cat << EOF
Usage: $(basename $0) COMMAND

  config  [OPTIONS]          Run the CLI tool
          --no-current-user  Run as root (Docker default) instead of the current user
  
  up      [OPTIONS]          Build, (re)create, and start all services in the background
          --dry-run          Disable Certbot to run all services locally
  
  build   [OPTIONS]          Build or rebuild all Docker images
          --no-cache         Do not use cache when building the images
EOF
    exit 1
}

case $1 in
  config)
    CMD=(docker-compose run --rm cli)
    export CURRENT_USER="$(id -u):$(id -g)"
    export DOCKER_GROUP="$(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3)"
    shift
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
      case $1 in
        --no-current-user)
          unset CURRENT_USER
          unset DOCKER_GROUP
          shift
          ;;
        *)
          echo "Unknown option $1"
          usage
          ;;
      esac
    done
    ;;
  up)
    CMD=(docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up -d)
    shift
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
      case $1 in
        --dry-run)
          export DRY_RUN=true
          shift
          ;;
        *)
          echo "Unknown option $1"
          usage
          ;;
      esac
    done
    ;;
  build)
    CMD=(docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml --profile config build)
    shift
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
      case $1 in
        --no-cache)
          CMD+=(--no-cache)
          shift
          ;;
        *)
          echo "Unknown option $1"
          usage
          ;;
      esac
    done
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unknown command $1"
    usage
    ;;
esac

"${CMD[@]}"
```

My `docker-compose-deploy.yml` file:

```
version: "3.2"

services: 
    # http://localhost:8080/
    webapp :
        build: .
        ports: 
        - "8080:8080"
        image: jetty:10.0.17-jdk11
        volumes:
        - ./target/spring-boot-leaflet-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/root.war
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "-I", "http://localhost:8080" ]
            interval: 1m
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 3
    
    # http://localhost:8080/
    cli:
        build: ./cli
        image: devops/letsencrypt-docker-compose-cli
        user: ${CURRENT_USER}
        group_add:
        - ${DOCKER_GROUP}
        environment:
        - COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
        - CURRENT_USER
        - DOCKER_GROUP
        volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./:/workdir
        profiles:
        - config

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        image: devops/nginx
        environment:
        - DRY_RUN
        volumes:
        - ./config.json:/letsencrypt-docker-compose/config.json:ro
        - ./nginx-conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        - ./nginx-conf/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
        - ./html:/var/www/html:ro
        - nginx_conf_ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
        - letsencrypt_certs:/etc/letsencrypt
        - certbot_acme_challenge:/var/www/certbot
        ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "nginx", "80"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            start_period: 30s
            retries: 10
        restart: unless-stopped
        # nginx needs the upstream service to be working 
        depends_on:
            webapp:
                condition: service_healthy

    certbot:
        build: ./certbot
        image: devops/certbot
        environment:
        - DRY_RUN
        volumes:
        - ./config.json:/letsencrypt-docker-compose/config.json:ro
        - letsencrypt_certs:/etc/letsencrypt
        - certbot_acme_challenge:/var/www/certbot
        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                "CMD-SHELL",
                'test -n "$$(ls -A /etc/letsencrypt/live/)" || test "$$DRY_RUN" == "true" || exit 1',
                ]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            start_period: 30s
            retries: 5
        depends_on:
            nginx:
                condition: service_healthy
        restart: unless-stopped
        
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
          MYSQL_USER: 'user'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
        ports:
          # <Port exposed> : <MySQL Port running inside container>
          - '3307:3306'
        expose:
          # Opens port 3307 on the container
          - '3307'
          # Where our data will be persisted
        volumes:
          - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
      
    cron:
        build: ./cron
        image: devops/cron
        environment:
        - COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
        - DRY_RUN
        volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./:/workdir:ro
        depends_on:
            certbot:
                condition: service_healthy
        restart: unless-stopped
          
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
  data-jetty-files: {}
  data-jetty-logs: {}

  nginx_conf_ssl:
  letsencrypt_certs:
  certbot_acme_challenge:
```

I've used the following commands to run the script:

```
chmod +x cli.sh
./cli.sh up --dry-run
```

I'm not sure why there syntax issues in the `docker-compose-deploy.yml` file, as this code runs locally but throws an error when on the virtual machine. The only related information I've found is possibly related to Docker Compose versions - on my local Windows machine it is v2.10.2, however on the virtual machine it is v1.25.0, which is the newest version on Linux. If this is the case, what changes can I make for this docker-compose file to work?

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: The issue is with the version of your docker-compose file. The 'condition' for depends_on  was removed in version:3, but re-introduced later.

Check this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060072/docker-compose-depends-on-with-condition-invalid-type-should-be-an-array

Comment: What if you use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`? These are two different tools, and the former may support newer syntax not supported by the latter. With Docker version 24.0.7 your compose file does not result in any errors.

Comment: @larsks Changing `docker-compose` to `docker compose` results in this error instead: `unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f`

Comment: service profiles was introduced in `1.28` version of `docker compose` & your vm happens to use `v1.25.0`. Try bumping the version to minimum `1.28`

Comment: "on the virtual machine it is v1.25.0, which is the newest version on Linux" - are you sure about that? v1.25.0 is more than four years old, and even v1 has received a lot of updates after v1.25.0

Comment: @NicoHaase About a month ago I tried upgrading it past v1.25.0, nothing worked, and I found a Stack Overflow post from September 2023 explaining there were compatibility problems with Linux and Docker, so I assumed there was no fix. I've finally managed to make it upgrade to v2.21.0 today, using the exact same approach I tried last month. It didn't work back then and suddenly works now. I'm still not sure why. Either way the problem is fixed now, thank you everyone for your help.