# restart docker container 1 if container 2 fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 docker containers when 1 fails i want to reset the other.

I thought restart_policy might be the correct area to look.

[restart_policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy)

But it seems a bit sparse on options. Nothing i see anywhere seems to the right kind of thing for reset dependant on each other.

Ideally i want to put the reset instructions in my docker-compose file.

any ideas?

ps) I'm doing this because if a container with code for a webscraper fails, then i need to reset the webdriver container it is using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the alternative to condition form of depends\_on in docker-compose Version 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710767/what-is-the-alternative-to-condition-form-of-depends-on-in-docker-compose-versio)

Comment: no it does not.