# Do not start service A unless service B is running docker swarm

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I have a ***nginx_proxy*** service that needs both ***nginx_1*** and ***nginx_2*** to be running if one of them is not running then the ***nginx_proxy*** will crash as it can resolve the IP of the service(s)

those are the ***nginx_proxy*** configurations:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name www.app1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nginx_1;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name www.app2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nginx_2;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

and this is the stack:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  nginx_proxy:
    {...}
  nginx_1:
    {...}
  nginx_2:
    {...}
```

Since ***depends_on*** doesn't work in the swarm mode, and also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710767/what-is-the-alternative-to-condition-form-of-depends-on-in-docker-compose-versio) gives `services.nginx.depends_on must be a list` error is there any other choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little script that will wait until all dependencies are up and running and then run the ***nginx_proxy***

this is [the script](https://gist.github.com/osamaAbdullah/34665cb3022478ea0d9f649fca37df1a)

also, add this to your nginx Dockerfile:

```
COPY --chmod=500 ./conf/wait_for_dependencies /wait_for_dependencies

CMD /wait_for_dependencies /docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

and pass the dependencies as an environment variable separated by `|`:

```
  nginx_proxy:
    {...}
    environment:
      - DEPENDENCIES=nginx_1|nginx_2
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and test then I realized something.

According to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/):

> The `docker stack deploy` command supports any Compose file of version "3.0" or above

And according to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on):

> The `depends_on` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file

So you don't have any other choices at this time.